# What is max row size of a table in Snowflake Database?

Tags: row, size, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am designing new system on Snowflake migrating data from Oracle/SQL Server DB. While designing I am thinking of creating "RAW" tables which has 2 columns i.e. "data_value variant" and "create_timestamp". With this design idea is to convert every incoming file format into parquet and load entire record into one variant column to support schema evolution. However in legacy DBs I see tables have columns that add upto 800MB Data Length by data types. With above design of raw layer want to understand what is max record size I can hold in Snowflake?

Still in design phase

Comment: VARIANT/STRING objects are limited to 16mb. Thus as long as each row is less than that you should be good. The sum of the column size does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

16 MB is limit for variant data type.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#data-size-limitations

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to be asking about two limits: row and column.

Each is answerable by how Snowflake stores data in [**micro-partitions**](https://select.dev/posts/snowflake-micro-partitions).

[image]

### Row size

I believe the answer here is 16MB of **compressed** data for the entire row.

Going off of [this article](https://select.dev/posts/snowflake-micro-partitions), the crucial two pieces of information are:

> A micro-partitions always contains complete rows of data

> A single micro-partition can contain up to 16MB of compressed data

This appears to be a fairly fundamental limit to Snowflake's data format. In theory you could of course distribute your data over multiple multi-partitions and [some people are doing exactly that](https://medium.com/snowflake/breaking-the-16-mb-limit-kinda-fe8d36658b).

### Column size

There should be no limitation on column size.

> As snowflake has no limit on table size, there is by extension no limit on the number of micro-partitions a single table can have.