# Snow flake row maximun size

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[This question has been already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563345/what-is-max-row-size-of-a-table-in-snowflake-database/75899501#75899501)

Nonetheless, it has not been answwered, therefore I'm asking it in more detail.

The data types can have a huge sizes such as images in SQL server which have more than 1Gb, nonetheless the **MAX ROW SIZE available in SQL server is 8Kb** and when you try to store data that would result in a row bigger than 8k the warning "data will be truncated" is issued.

The samne happens in **mysql where the MAX ROW SIZE is 16Kb.**

Considering what is mentioned above, I haven't been able to find the max row size in snowflake, could anyone bring light in this issue?

Comment: If you are referring to the maximum size of a string, then it's in the documentation pretty clearly as 16,777,216 bytes.  If you are trying to store unstructured data in Snowflake, you should look into how unstructured data works.  You wouldn't want to load it into a column like "blob" data type, but rather reference the file that is stored on blob storage.  Check the docs on unstructured data for more details on that.

Comment: Is not the max size of the string, is the maximum size of the row, for example in SQL server you can't have more than 8Kb of data no matter the data type. I would like to know the maximum value in Snowflake. It is not the maximum size of the data type but the maximum allowed value that can be stored in the data row

Comment: You are conflating "what can be stored in the database (aka larger files) with ROWs" in the SQL Server story. SQL cares very much about row size to do memory allocations, this framework of thinking does not apply to Snowflake. Once you see it this, you will also see this question is mostly meaningless. Perhaps instead of talking in terms of absolute limits that SQL Server has, ask questions about "what you want to do". Or "how to do it". Or "in SQL Server X is not possible, how would I solve this in Snowflake"

Comment: Your question was answered in the question you linked to (by @SimeonPilgrim). Why do you think it wasn’t answered - what other answer do you think there is?

Comment: What you are actually saying is that, I can have limiteless tables with string columns each of them of the size of almost 16MB as long as my snowflake storage is able to save it? since it does not have the same issue of allocating memory sQL server has?. For example, I could have a table with 10 columns, each of them with a string of 16MB of characters?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is max row size of a table in Snowflake Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563345/what-is-max-row-size-of-a-table-in-snowflake-database)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find in the docs an explicit definition, but the maximum row size in Snowflake is 16MB (compressed).

Related remarks in the docs:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#data-size-limitations

If you have larger rows, a UDTF can read binary files too:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/breaking-the-16-mb-limit-kinda-fe8d36658b